# Splitting lists in Python and separating each element

Tags: python, list

I would like to split each element of list to new list, and then split each word in inner list to separate element. Thanks for the help!

```
listaTest = ['Anna,Annowska,450', 'Bartosz,Bartecki,500']

listaTestNew = [['Anna','Annowska','450'],['Bartosz','Bartecki','500']]
```

Comment: Well that's just one split. What do you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
listaTest = ['Anna,Annowska,450', 'Bartosz,Bartecki,500']
print(list(map(lambda x: x.split(','), listaTest)))
```

This prints:

```
[['Anna', 'Annowska', '450'], ['Bartosz', 'Bartecki', '500']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
new=[]
listaTest = ['Anna,Annowska,450', 'Bartosz,Bartecki,500']
for i in listaTest:
    parts=i.split(",")
    new.append(parts)
```

Hope it helps